# How to rewrite expression x=>!x to x=>x!=true and x=>x to x=>x==true

Tags: c#, linq, expression, expressionvisitor

Asume, that we expressions like this:

```
someIQueryable.Where(x => x.SomeBoolProperty)
someIQueryable.Where(x => !x.SomeBoolProperty)
```

I need to convert (rewrite using expression visitor) expressions like above to expressions like this:

```
someIQueryable.Where(x => x.SomeBoolProperty == true)
someIQueryable.Where(x => x.SomeBoolProperty != true)
```

NOTE: rewriter must work in more general case too, if we have more complex expressions:

```
 someIQueryable.Where((x => x.SomeBoolProperty && x.SomeIntProperty > 0) || !x.SomeOtherBoolProperty))
```

Comment: Are you simply asking for a complete, working solution? What have you tried?

Comment: What you want to achieve? Where is difference? It will be translated to same query.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Yes, i`m converting this to SQL query. But unfortunately when i translating them, the resulting query is not valid

Comment: @GorRustamyan that sounds like a serious bug in the specific LINQ implementation - can I ask what provider that is?

Comment: @Marc Gravell, Dont worry, this is my own provider implemetation

Comment: @Gor personally, I'd say "fix your provider" ;p

Comment: @Gor note I edited my answer to provide a very important test for various comparison operations - you would definitely need that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like:

```
static class BooleanComplexifier
{
    public static Expression<T> Process<T>(Expression<T> expression)
        where T : class
    {
        var body = expression.Body;
        if (body.Type == typeof(bool))
        {
            switch(body.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.Equal:
                case ExpressionType.NotEqual:
                case ExpressionType.GreaterThan:
                case ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                case ExpressionType.LessThan:
                case ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual:
                    return expression;
                case ExpressionType.Not:
                    body = Expression.NotEqual(
                        ((UnaryExpression)body).Operand,
                        Expression.Constant(true));
                    break;
                default:
                        body = Expression.Equal(body,
                        Expression.Constant(true));
                    break;
            }
            return Expression.Lambda<T>(body, expression.Parameters);
        }
        return expression;
    }   
}
```

with:

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> x = foo => foo.IsAlive,
    y = foo => !foo.IsAlive;

var a = BooleanComplexifier.Process(x); // foo => foo.IsAlive == true
var b = BooleanComplexifier.Process(y); // foo => foo.IsAlive != true
//...
class Foo
{
    public bool IsAlive { get;set; }
}
```

---

For more complex processing, an `ExpressionVisitor` may be necessary:

```
class BooleanComplexifier : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public static Expression<T> Process<T>(Expression<T> expression)
    {
        return (Expression<T>)new BooleanComplexifier().Visit(expression);
    }

    int bypass;
    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    {
        if (bypass == 0 && node.Type == typeof(bool))
        {
            switch (node.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.And: // bitwise & - different to &&
                case ExpressionType.Or: // bitwise | - different to ||
                case ExpressionType.Equal:
                case ExpressionType.NotEqual:
                    bypass++;
                    var result = base.VisitBinary(node);
                    bypass--;
                    return result;
            }
        }
        return base.VisitBinary(node);
    }
    protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
    {
        if (bypass == 0 && node.Type == typeof(bool))
        {
            switch(node.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.Not:
                    bypass++;
                    var result = Expression.NotEqual(
                        base.Visit(node.Operand),
                        Expression.Constant(true));
                    bypass--;
                    return result;
            }
        }
        return base.VisitUnary(node);
    }
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if(bypass == 0 && node.Type == typeof(bool))
        {
            return Expression.Equal(
                base.VisitMember(node),
                Expression.Constant(true));
        }
        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hehe, nice name for the class :)

Comment: This fails on z = foo => foo.IsAlive && !foo.IsAlive. // It produces foo => ((foo.IsAlive && Not(foo.IsAlive)) == True)

Comment: @Gor indeed, but the question didn't specify that as a requirement ;p If the scenario is **specifically** any access to a boolean property that doesn't involve != / ==, then that can be done - but needs a different approach: 2 minutes...

Comment: Yes. That is why i write note. In fact, the problem is, how to detect cases like this. One method is to check, if parent expression is binary boolean expression. But this leads to problem of finding parent expression.

Comment: @GorRustamyan if you needed complete control, you would have to keep a `Stack<Expression>` of the parents, pushing-and-popping (presumably in the `Visit` method), so you can check the entire ancestry